# How to build a link without preloading the model?

Tags: ember.js

Right now, we're building our links like that:

```
<a {{action showComment comment href=true}}>Show</a>
```

That generates a link which looks like `/comments/45`.

Unfortunately, that only works when we preload the comment - even though we already have the ID of the comment. Is it possible without preloading the comment?

Something that might look like:

```
<a {{action showComment comment_id href=true}}>Show</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the actual question here? This is not quite clear to me.

So your current action handler looks like this:

```
showComment : function(comment){
  //do your stuff with the model
}
```

Now your desired solution could look like this:

```
<a {{action showCommentById comment_id href=true}}>Show</a>
```

And the corresponding handler:

```
showCommentById : function(commentId){
  var comment = App.Comment.findById(commentId); // i assume you have this retrieval method or something like it
  this.showComment(comment);
},
showComment : function(comment){
  //do your stuff with the model
}
```

**Would this work in your case?** Or did you intend something else?

---

**UPDATE: OP would like have all Data Handling in the route**
Your Route should handle the action "showCommentById" that i did propose before:

```
App.ArticlesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    events : {
        showCommentById : function(commentId){
            var comment = App.Comment.findByIds(commentId); // i assume you have this retrieval 
            this.transitionTo("root.articles.comment", comment);
        }
    }
});
```

So actually **you are free to decide where to handle actions** in your app.

Comment: This works, BUT! We want to keep loading of data (call find functions on models) in our router's route. Especially in the new router api, loading of models within a route is solved very nice, so i am not sure if it is best practice, to do this in our "navigating-functions" (like showComment), as you suggested.

Comment: But you easily delegate that call to your route? Can you put up a fiddle? Then i could understand your current App structure.

Comment: I've tried to put a simple example on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AhgBh/. It will not work, but it shows a little bit more precises our structure. Welcome for inputs!