# Trying to {{linkTo}} an arrayController?

Tags: ember.js

How can I `{{linkTo}}` comments inside a blog post that have not been loaded yet?

**Desired solution**

```
{{#linkTo "comments" articles.id}}View comments{{/linkTo}}
```

should lead to

```
/#/articles/123/comments
```

The model looks like that:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend
    text: DS.attr "string"
    comments: DS.hasMany "App.Comment"
```

**What I've already tried**

- [In latest Ember, how do you link to a route with just the id/name of a model, rather than providing all of its attributes in the linking page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367517/in-latest-ember-how-do-you-link-to-a-route-with-just-the-id-name-of-a-model-ra)
- [How to build a link without preloading the model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980895/how-to-build-a-link-without-preloading-the-model)
- [Has no method 'addArrayObserver' during {{#linkTo}} click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177093/has-no-method-addarrayobserver-during-linkto-click)

All of these "solutions" seem to be workarounds rather than a simple solution to what I think is a simple task.